# CodeIgniter: separating admin-, user- and partner sites

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

My CodeIgniter web application must be divided in three big parts:

1. Admin - unlimited access to editing, deleting and creating data
2. User - read-only
3. Partner - limited access to editing data, no deleting, no creating

All parts are independent from each other, but work with the same database.

My question is - what is the best way to keep them apart?

I see two possible ways:

1. Subfolder in controller directory. Not good - if i create an Admin-subfolder i wont be able to do something like this admin/events/controller_name.php or admin/places/controller_name.php. And without such a separation it will be a mess.
2. Separate applications on subdomains (admin.sitename.com/ , partner.sitename.com/). Also not very good - i will have to duplicate all models (which are same in all cases), libraries etc.

Are there any better ways to do this? It would be really nice if i could somehow use different sets of controllers and only one set of models/libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate controller libraries for each.

- Users - normal controller
- Admin  - admin_controller extends controller
- Partner - partner_controller extends controller

Read here: http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/02/CodeIgniter-Base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY

Separate folders in Controllers and Views to keep the functionality separate. Use your routing to sort how you reach each.

Answer (score 0):

domain.com/admin/page/231

domain.com/user/page/231

domain.com/partner/page/231

you dont even have to route it - will automatically go to different classes - which can share the same models. also - do the login validation in the class constructor, by calling a method (probably in a model), like IF $this->login_model->verifyAdmin() that way you can change the mechanics of verifyAdmin() later, and you wont have to change anything in your class constructor.